# What is worldsheet in strings theory?

Tags: string-theory

What is [worldsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldsheet) in strings theory?
What is its difference with [worldline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) in particle physics?

Comment: This would be very easily Googled. Can you extend your question to explain what it is about the concept of a world sheet that is puzzling you?

Comment: @JohnRennie
what it is about the concept of a world sheet that is puzzling you? 
I don't know what is Its difference with worldline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of a point particle, if you imagine that as it traverses its trajectory it can leave a behind a ``trail'' marking every point that it has visited then this trail would take the form of a one dimensional line. This is the particle's worldline.

Now consider a string -- it's an extended one dimensional object, so each point on the string needs to be capable of leaving its mark (or trail) simultaneously with every other. Now what happens if you imagine a string moving through space, where each point on the string marks the path it traverses? Can you see that the resulting trail, consisting of the marks from each point on the string, will in fact take the form of a two-dimensional surface? This is the string worldsheet.