# If worldlines are real, wouldn't energy-time uncertainty make stable particles infinitely massive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, mass

In his famous 1908 "Space and Time" lecture, Minkowski introduced the concept of worldlines and thus of a block universe with a single remarkable sentence: *"To never let a yawning emptiness, let us imagine that everywhere and at any time something perceivable exists."*

In Minkowski's substance-filled block universe, the worldline of a particle such as a proton would require a finite mass-energy density per unit of time simply for the particle to exist and have a finite rest mass. However, in modern quantum theory — which was in its pre-infancy in 1908 — time as measured in experiments has no such sharp boundary. Time at the experimental level instead has a thickness that is inversely proportional to the mass-energy stability of the particles involved.

This is a curious thing, since defining the mass of a particle in any experimentally meaningful version of a substance-filled block universe necessarily requires some form of integration of the mass-energy density of the experimentally accessible subsegment of that particle's worldline, which is defined by the rules of quantum mechanics. Unfortunately, those rules do not provide any obvious method by which to define the extremely precise time brackets needed for a well-defined, stable rest mass. Quite the contrary is true, in fact, since energy-time uncertainty would appear to suggest that the more stable the particle is, the broader the brackets of its mass-defining worldline time integral will be. The *reducto absurdum* is that protons and electrons left undisturbed for long periods of time in a block universe should acquire rest masses that trend towards infinity. Similar arguments would of course also apply to other particle properties such as electrical charge, which to be experimentally meaningful would also require integration of an associated charge density per unit of worldline.

So my question is this: For modern block universe interpretations that implicitly (and as best I can see, unavoidably) accept Minkowski's casual insertion of "substance" throughout spacetime, what is the precise, quantum-compatible mathematical model by which the stable masses of fundamental particles are derived from their worldlines in the presence of energy-time uncertainty?

Answer (score 2):

I will turn my comment into an answer, in case it is deleted as such:

You state in your question

> what is the precise, quantum-compatible mathematical model by which stable masses of fundamental particles are derived

In the mainstream [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which is a quantum field theoretical model, the masses in the table of elementary particles are axiomatically assigned , and also are point particles . There is no derivation. The mass is the "length" of the four vector assigned to a particle, and is called the invariant mass because it is invariant under Lorenz transformations.

From the fundamental particles, composite particles acquire their mass by the addition of the four vectors of the fundamental particles.

I cannot answer about world lines , i.e. in the realm of General Relativity. But mixing quantum mechanics with GR is still  a research problem, AFAIK. In string theories,  there is quantization of gravity , and a string theorist might  answer about the world lines of strings.

Comment: maybe this is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397361/

Comment: anna v, thanks, nice to see your name again. This is one of those curious issues for which the only answer I could see from what I've read is exactly what you said: Because the particle is _declared_ to be a point, which itself is a remarkably difficult statement to reconcile with real, fully physical worldlines. Fascinating. BTW, after HAWC March 30, it's just gotten even harder to take string theory as anything more than a very successful half-century exercise in very bad science funding. I don't even bother to look up the papers anymore.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what  "HAWC March 30" means. I am a strong believer that string theories which can embed the standard model are the future particle modeling tools. World lines become worldsheets in string theory , and might be liable to an uncertainty. It is necessary for any theory of everything to embed the standard model, because it is an encapsulation of practically all data up to now. Axioms are necessary to pick up correct solutions of QFT, and the success of the SM means that the point particle  assumption is good  to the level of errors we have.

Comment: Anna, it's just well-done, large-scale, old-fashioned experimentation disproving a hypothesis: Strings are too huge & clunky to be compatible with good ol' Lorentz invariance. Space-time is simpler, subtler, and more beautiful and subtle than that.


Phys. Rev. Lett. 124, 131101 (2020) - Constraints on Lorentz Invariance Violation from HAWC Observations of Gamma Rays above 100 TeV

https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.124.131101

Comment: Also, for readers who are interested in why string theory (or to be historically precise, superstring theory) experimentally violates the most basic Gang of Four (Poincare, Lorentz, Einstein, Minkowski) smoothness features of spacetime, here's a fun Ethan Siegel summary:


Astrophysics Signal Does What The LHC Cannot: Constrain Quantum Gravity And String Theory

https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/04/03/astrophysics-signal-does-what-the-lhc-cannot-constrain-quantum-gravity-and-string-theory/

Comment: the link says the opposite, it is just an improvement over a limit to Lorenz invariance violation, have not found a violation. the pdf: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.08070.pdf  Strings are consistent both with Lorenz and with general relativity constraints so I really do not know what you are talking about.